How to accept invalid certs using lapin?
consumption works fine locally when using amqp
let conn = Connection::connect(&addr, ConnectionProperties::default())
          .await
          .expect("connects to rabbitmq ok");

but when deploying to test env I need to use amqps and it's getting an invalid cert error so I tried to accept invalid certs
Code I'm using to connect is based on https://github.com/amqp-rs/lapin/blob/main/examples/custom_tls_connection.rs
let uri = addr.parse::<AMQPUri>().unwrap();

        let connect = move |uri: &AMQPUri| {
          uri.connect().and_then(|stream| {
            let mut tls_builder = NativeTlsConnector::builder();
            tls_builder.danger_accept_invalid_certs(true);
            stream.into_native_tls(
              &tls_builder.build().expect("TLS configuration failed"),
              &uri.authority.host,
            )
          })
        };

        let conn = Connection::connector(uri, Box::new(connect), ConnectionProperties::default())
          .await
          .expect("connects to rabbitmq ok");

excepton I'm getting is
thread 'main' panicked at src/event_consumer.rs:61:10:
connects to rabbitmq ok: IOError(Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: InvalidCertificate(UnknownIssuer) })
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at ./rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/std/src/panicking.rs:645:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at ./rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/panicking.rs:72:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at ./rustc/07dca489ac2d933c78d3c5158e3f43beefeb02ce/library/core/src/result.rs:1649:5
   3: ord::event_consumer::EventConsumer::run::{{closure}}
   4: tokio::runtime::runtime::Runtime::block_on
   5: ord::arguments::Arguments::run
   6: ord::main
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.

Similar issue seems to be https://github.com/amqp-rs/lapin/issues/396 but RustlsConnector does not have a way to accept invalid certs from what I can tell.
Any ideas how to accept invalid certs using lapin?
